# как обработать клик по строке в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Много информации по `DataGridView`, но я не нашел информации по `DataGrid`. Как обработать клик по строке в DataGrid?

Comment: У `DataGrid` событий вагон и [маленькая тележка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid_events(v=vs.110).aspx), вас какое интересует?

Comment: я события видел, но интересует клик именно по строке в гриде..

Answer (score 3):

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120616/wpf-datagrid-selected-row-clicked-event)

Вы можете использовать `ItemContainerStyle`

```
<DataGrid ... >
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_DoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Обработчик:

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // execute some code
}
```

Comment: просто добавляем среди колонок в wpf и при нажатии на строку можно будет считать?

Comment: @Nikolay да, но почему бы не перейти на использование DataGridView?

Comment: Просто считаю, что технология не должна пугать, ее надо изучать. Да и Windows.Forms использовать не хотелось бы